# Count rows with limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get out of database 5 recently added articles by user and also count how many did he added in general. This was my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE user = :user
ORDER BY publish_date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

What I simply changed to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM articles
    WHERE user = :user
    ORDER BY publish_date DESC
    LIMIT 5)
```

But this gives me an empty array. I don't want to split it into 2 queries, what can be the result?

Comment: The second query lacks an alias name for the subquery at the end. Simply add some letter at the end to make it valid. The result you'll get will be 5 or less of course, because you limit the articles thus.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @ThorstenKettern Yea but when I do it, it just gives me back the count, I want to also get back an articles data

Comment: Then what shall your result look like? Either you can show five rows with the last articles or you can show one value for the total count. A result combining the two is hard to imagine. Please edit your request as jarlh suggested and show the expected result.